# Which target on msbuild create package

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have tfs 2012 server and solution: mvc project and windows azure project. I write on msbuild target, which copy some file. I need start this is task, after msbuild create package. I write this is target, but it start, when msbuild doesn't create package.

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
 ...
```

So can you write me, after which target I need start my target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CreateWebDeployPackage>True</CreateWebDeployPackage>
```